# Does precision and scale of NUMBER influence the behaviour of ResultSet.getObject()

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

-Oracle 11g
-Oracle thin driver

When a column is defined as NUMBER the getObject method on ResultSet will return a BigDecimal type. My question is, If we where to change the column definition to NUMBER(19,0) would the driver know to convert this to a Long when we called getObject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think no.
[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31226/datamap.htm) the document says the SQL data types DEC, DECIMAL, NUMBER, NUMERIC are mapped into java.math.BigDecimal.